# Nested for loop

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am trying to list files in a nested zip as below.
It is not listing files in second level.

For example:

`abc.zip` contains `test1.zip`, `test2.zip`, `test3.zip`

`pqr.zip` contains `test4.zip`, `test5.zip`, `test6.zip`

```
for f in *.zip
do
  unzip -l ${f}
  for p in ${f}
  do 
    unzip -l ${p}
  done
done
```

Comment: That first `unzip` does nothing (it puts some stuff on the output, but that is not used). The 2nd for iterates over one item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it without actually unzipping the top files in a sub-folder.

Something like this:

```
set -e
for f in *.zip
do
  n=`basename -- "${f}" .zip`
  mkdir -- "${n}"
  cd -- "${n}"
  unzip ../"${f}"
  for p in *.zip
  do
    unzip -l -- "${p}"
  done
  cd ..
  rm -rf -- "${n}"
done
```

You should probably verify whether `${n}` already exists and if so generate an error. You could also use a temporary filename for the sub-directory:

```
dir=`mktemp -d zip-files.XXXXXX`
```

Then do `cd "${dir}"` and `rm -rf "${dir}"` once done.

**Updates:**

The `set -e` is used to make sure that if something goes wrong then the script stops. Especially, if the `mkdir -- "${m}"` fails, the `cd -- "${m}"` will fail too and thus the `cd ..` would get you at the wrong directory level and that's where the `rm -rf -- "${n}"` becomes dangerous.

Another way to make the `cd ..` statement safer is to memorize that directory before the `for` loop and use that path like so:

```
topdir=`pwd`
for ...
do
  ...
  cd "$topdir"   # instead of `cd ..`
  ...
done
```

That way the `rm -rf -- "${n}"` will only operate in `$topdir`.

The use of the temporary directory will also make things a lot safer since that way whatever the filenames in the top zip file, the directory creation/removal will work as expected.

Comment: Your initial statement is incorrect [as I have demonstrated](/a/636699). Also note that in most Bourne-like shells, parameter expansions need to be quoted. See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) and also [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/590210) about the missing `--`s.

Comment: Your `$f` and `$n` will be identical (if `$f` is without spaces and filename globbing characters). You're lacking quotes. If any Zip archive is called `* .zip`, you will be removing the wrong files with your `rm` (but that's only one of the issues).

Comment: I've added an update with your info. Using the `mktemp` and quotes would make my first script much safer indeed.

Comment: A safer way to temporarily change directory is to do it in a subshell: `(cd -- "$dir" && for file in *.zip; do unzip -l -- "$file"; done)`

Answer (score 4):

With a combination of libarchive's `bsdtar` and GNU `tar`, you can list the contents of those nested archives without having to extract them on disk:

```
for f in *.zip; do
  bsdtar -cf - --include='*.zip' "@$f" | tar -xf - --to-command='bsdtar tvf -'
done
```

GNU `tar` can pipe members of archives to commands upon extraction with `--to-command` but only supports `tar` archive formats.

`bsdtar` supports all sorts of archive formats beside `tar` ones (including `zip` ones), doesn't have the equivalent of GNU `tar`'s `--to-command` (AFAIK), but can convert archive formats on the fly.

Comment: In many cases, people do not want to install yet another tool, although this is a nice trick.

Comment: @AlexisWilke, `bsdtar` is **the** tool to extract archives. The OP will likely have had to install `unzip`. `bsdtar` would have been a much better choice.

Comment: unfortunately, bsdtar does not appear to be available in Ubuntu and Arch/Manjaro.

Comment: @sitaram It is on Debian based systems including Ubuntu.. Used to be in a `bsdtar` package; now in `libarchive-tools` (which now also includes a `bsdcpio` command). It's becoming a de facto standard. I'd be surprised if any GNU/Linux distribution doesn't at least have a package for it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas -- indeed, now I found it; thank you for that!  I should have searched for the filename instead of package name, earlier.

Answer (score 2):

If GNU Parallel is installed:

```
extract_list() {
  mkdir "$1"
  cd "$1"
  unzip ../"$1".zip
  parallel unzip -l ::: *.zip
  cd ..
  rm -rf "$1"
}
export -f extract_list

parallel extract_list {.} ::: *.zip
```